# Установить постоянный фокус на textarea

Tags: html, javascript

На страничке есть textarea, нужно, чтобы на нем был постоянный фокус, куда бы не нажимал мышкой.

Comment: Вроде [так](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/85zr3fwy/) получилось. Проверьте разные варианты.

Comment: Он ведь пропадает, если мышкой по пустом кликнуть, есть ли возможности установить принудительный фокус, чтобы все время на на окне textarea находился.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, может, дело в браузере. У меня Chromium 37.0.2062.120, и куда бы я, на jsfiddle, не кликал, никуда фокус не девается.

Comment: На трех браузерах проверил, фокус пропадает.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, можно психонуть и навесить побольше событий на все элементы страницы )) Например, [вот так][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/85zr3fwy/1/

Comment: Надо только на одном.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, да, был не прав. Firefox и Rekonq не заценили мой подход.

Comment: Еще опера и ИЕ.

Comment: Убейте все tabindex, кроме tabindex текстарии.

Answer (score 1):

Типа так?

```
<script>
document.onclick = function(event) {
 document.getElementById("puk").focus();
};
</script>
<textarea id="puk"></textarea>
<textarea ></textarea>
```

Comment: Вот это именно то, что нужно.